# You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type....SVG webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, webpack

I have a problem when I try to build my component using webpack.
The console shows this:

```
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|
|   return (
>     <svg viewBox={`0 0 ${width} ${height}`} className='simple-line-chart'>
|       <Axis
|         padding={padding} axisLineColor={axisLineColor}
 @ ./src/index.js 8:17-43
```

This is my config.js

```
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loaders: ['babel-loader?presets[]=es2015']
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "react-svg-loader",
            options: {
              jsx: true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
  }
```

I'm not sure if I have to use react-svg-loader because I'm not importing a svg, instead I'm creating one.
Thank's for the support!!

Comment: Could you please provide stablitz or codesandbox with issue reproduced?

Comment: Hi, the error isn't in the component, i think is in the loaders

Comment: That's what I think as well as `svg` element is working perfectly fine for me.